# How to declare array in method

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently having to write a method that takes in two parameters: an array of integers called data and an integer called num.  The purpose of this method is to count the amount of times that number shows up in the array.  I am having trouble figuring out how to declare the array in the method.  I was wondering if there was any easier way that I did below:

**Method**

```
public static void countNumbers( int data[], int num ) {
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i] == num)
                count++;
        }
        if (count == 0)
            System.out.println("There are no " + num + "'s in the array.");
        if (count == 1)
            System.out.println("There is one " + num + " in the array.");
        if (count > 1)
            System.out.println("There are: " + count + " " + num + "'s in the array.");
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int firstArray[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Methods.countNumbers(firstArray, 2);
    }
```

So I was wondering if you could directly declare the array within the `countNumbers(data,num)` any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your question -- you declare the array in the method parameter and appear to do so appropriately. So what is this all about? What confuses you.

Comment: I was wondering if there was any way to declare the array within the method such as: Methods.countNumbers(int firstArray[] = {1,2,3} , 2);

Comment: If you don't reference it anywhere else (you don't need it anywhere else) just do Methods.countNumbers({1, 2, 3}, 2)

Comment: @MCMastery I don't think that's going to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Methods.countNumbers(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5}, 2);
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much. I can not accept an answer just yet though!

Comment: Ha, glad I could be of help. And don't worry, you can always come back once you've got more rep. :)